# blogslibv_8.3 linking the libraires in Visual c++ 2008

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, blogs

Can anyone give me the procedure for building a blogslib library containing code in vc++ 2008 edition?

The official documentation gives it for vc++ 2006.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to expand on what blogslib is - Google was no help (to me, anyway). Also, I assume you mean VC++2005 instead of 2006.

Comment: error says can't find cvblogslib.lib 
well in the downloaded directory.. i can't find cvblogslib.lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my answer I presume you mean cvBlob library not Blog one. If I got it wrong then ignore me.

I haven't used that blob library but it seems that you need to add the lib file that you have compiled into the Linker of your project (Linker->Input) (and also check if you have the additional paths set in there so it can find it in the right directory (Linker->General))

You can also try - cvBlob (google it to find the link) - just include 2-3 files to your project and compile. I used that for my project - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o4Dcr0t_nI

If you need any other help feel free to ask.